# How set a text at particular XY coordinate in MS Outlook 2007?

Tags: c#, outlook

Using C#, I need to send a mail with set the texts at particular XY coordinates in MS Outlook 2007. What is the way to set text at XY coordinates? In MS Outlook 2003 mail generate properly using style, but style is not working in 2007.  Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

can you explain a little more what you want to achive? In the mean time

Outook 2007 uses the word editor under the hood so it possible to get that

```
Item.GetInspector.GetWordEditor
```

Then you can use the word [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243297.aspx)

Comment: hi 76mel,currently i am sending email through code and set content at various location using "position:absolute", it works well in MS outlook 2003 but in 2007 cannot works.